# When using Ember Simple Auth is it possible to tell the difference between a token expiring and the user pressing logout

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I've turned off refreshtokens as we currently do not use them.

app/authenticators/oauth2.js

```
export default OAuth2PasswordGrant.extend({
  serverTokenEndpoint: ENV.APP.harrierServerTokenEndPoint,
  refreshAccessTokens: false,
  makeRequest: function(url, data) {
  ...
```

After 12 hours our users token expires and they are correctly taken to the login route.

My end goal is to display a message on the login route is they came there because of token expiry, i.e.

```
{{if fromExpire 'Your session expired, please login again' ''}}
```

I'm happy to populate `fromExpire` property from a url query param or otherwise. The step I'm missing is how to get Ember Simple Auth to tell the login route it is coming from token expiry, as opposed to a first time user or the user having logged themselves out.

Comment: Could you implement the reverse logic? Add a `fromLogout` query param and set it to true if the user clicked the `logout` button? If the query param is not present then it means that the token expired.

Comment: Nearly - but this wouldn't cover first time users where we wouldn't want to show the message